# Create PowerPoint presention on the fly using C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have tried looking into the creation of a PowerPoint presentation using C# but i was not able to find how i would clone slides from a template and add charts to a presentation slide  on the fly using C#.

After the presentation has been created save the file as well.

Using Aspose.slide for .NET

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you want to create PowerPoint presentation in C#? There are many 3rd party software, but can you tell why do you need to create PowerPoints through C#?

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also refer to the following useful links:

1. [Cloning Slides including Images and Charts in PowerPoint presentations & Using Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool](http://www.exsilio.com/blog/post/2011/03/21/Cloning-Slides-including-Images-and-Charts-in-PowerPoint-presentations-Using-Open-XML-SDK-20-Productivity-Tool.aspx)
2. [Add Chart on the fly to PowerPoint](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/15/t/1429.aspx)
3. [Create PowerPoint .PPT programmatically using C#](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/create-powerpoint-ppt-programmatically-using-c/)
4. [How to create a PowerPoint presentation using C# and embed a Picture to the slide](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/how-to-create-a-powerpoint-presentation-using-c-and-embed-a-picture-to-the-slide/)

Comment: this is using open xml right... hiow about if i was to use aspose.slide

Comment: two of the links are dead!